# Averaging over window function leads to StackOverflowError

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to determine the average timespan between dates in a Dataframe column by using a window-function. Materializing the Dataframe however throws a Java exception.

Consider the following example:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext, Window, functions
from datetime import datetime

sc = SparkContext()
sq = HiveContext(sc)

data = [
    [datetime(2014,1,1)],
    [datetime(2014,2,1)],
    [datetime(2014,3,1)],
    [datetime(2014,3,6)],
    [datetime(2014,8,23)],
    [datetime(2014,10,1)],
]
df = sq.createDataFrame(data, schema=['ts'])

ts = functions.col('ts')

w = Window.orderBy(ts)
diff = functions.datediff(
    ts,
    functions.lag(ts, count=1).over(w)
)

avg_diff = functions.avg(diff)
```

While `df.select(diff.alias('diff')).show()` correctly renders as

```py
+----+
|diff|
+----+
|null|
|  31|
|  28|
|   5|
| 170|
|  39|
+----+
```

doing `df.select(avg_diff).show()` gives a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

Am I wrong to assume that this should work? And if so, what am I doing wrong and what could I do instead?

I am using the Python API on Spark 1.6

When I do `df2 = df.select(diff.alias('diff'))` and then do

```py
df2.select(functions.avg('diff'))
```

there's no error. Unfortunately that is not an option in my current setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug in Catalyst but. Chaining methods should work just fine:

```
df.select(diff.alias('diff')).agg(functions.avg('diff'))
```

Nevertheless I would be careful here. Window functions shouldn't be used to perform global (without `PARTITION BY` clause) operations. These move all data to a single partition and perform a sequential scan. Using RDDs could be a better choice here.

Comment: In my actual application I would partition the window by some key and then use the aggregation in a `groupby`. If I defined the window as `Window.partitionby(key).orderby(ts)` for a subsequent `df.groupby(key).agg(avg_diff)` things should be fine, right? Despite the fact of course that this still throws the error.

Comment: Yes, it should be OK.